# MongoDB query help: $elemMatch in nested objects

Tags: mongodb

```
> db.test.insert({"a" : { "b" : { "c" : { "d1" : [ "e1" ],
                                          "d2" : [ "e2" ], 
                                          "d3" : [ "e3", "e4" ], 
                                          "d4" : [ "e5", "e6" ] } } } })
> db.test.find({'a.b.c' : {$exists : true}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4daf2ccd697ebaacb10976ec"), "a" : { "b" : { "c" : { "d1" : [ "e1" ], "d2" : [ "e2" ], "d3" : [ "e3", "e4" ], "d4" : [ "e5", "e6" ] } } } }
```

But none of these work:

```
> db.test.find({'a.b': "c"})
> db.test.find({'a.b': {$elemMatch : {"c" : {$exists: true}}}})
> db.test.find({'a.b': {$elemMatch : {$elemMatch : {$all : ["e1"] }}}})
```

Suppose I don't know what the values of `c` and `d1`...`d4` are. Is there a generic way to search the nested-objects' structure for particular values?

I thought that was what `$elemMatch` was for.

Thank you.

Comment: Check $elemMatch [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24elemMatch).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I thought that was what $elemMatch was for...

From [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/): *Using the $elemMatch query operator, you can match an entire document within an array.*

This does not sounds like what you're looking for.

> Is there a generic way to search the nested-objects' structure for particular values?

It sounds like you want to search *"everything in object 'c' for an instance of 'e1'"*.

MongoDB supports two related features, but the features not quite what you're looking for.

- *Reach into objects*, dot notation: `db.test.find({'a.b.c.d1' : 'e1'})`
- *Read through arrays*: `db.test.find({'a.b.c.d4' : 'e5'})

It sounds like you're looking for the ability to do both at the same time. You want to "reach into objects" and "read through arrays" in the same query.

Unfortunately, I do not know of such a feature. You may want to [file a feature request](http://jira.mongodb.org/) for this.

Comment: Thanks, I did [request the feature](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2989).

Answer (score 2):

I believe the query you're looking for is

```
db.test.find({ 'a.b.c': { '$exists': true } });
```

To your credit, you were very close!

Comment: yes, this query works, but I'm looking for a way to search by the key or value of the nested object when you don't know what the intermediate key (`b` in this case) is.

Comment: I [filed a feature request](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2989), so hopefully this will be available soon.